# Xpress Mosel - Command to stop an optimization after a certain amount of time

Tags: optimization, command, timeout

I'm currenlty trying to resolve an optimization problem but it's way to big and the software can't handle it fast enough. What's the command to stop it after a certain amount of time? 
Can't find it on documentation

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are working with Xpress Optimizer (module "mmxprs"), you can set a time limit via

```
setparam("XPRS_MAXTIME", 60)   ! time limit of 60 seconds (if solving MIP: continue until first solution is found) 
setparam("XPRS_MAXTIME", -60)  ! hard time limit of 60 seconds
```

(see the Xpress Optimizer reference manual for the documentation of the 'MAXTIME' control).

If you are working with a different solver, you need to check the corresponding solver manual to find out the name of the parameter to use for this purpose (for example, with the "kalis" module there is a parameter "KALIS_MAX_COMPUTATION_TIME").

An easy way of seeing the available parameters for a given solver module (e.g. mmxprs) is this command:

```
mosel exam -p mmxprs
```